# How do controllers receive data from forms submitted by POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

It's been bothering me for sometimes. I can see plenty of examples where actions read data from a View (data sent by POST) in many different ways. Specially in this topic [on handling multiple submit buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework), for instance:

the model is read from a view:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Model model)
{
}
```

or only `ID` and then `TryUpdateModel` somehow knows which to update

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? PropertyID)
{
    //...
    Model modelToEdit = dbContext.Objects.Find(PropertyID);
    if(TryUpdateModel(modelToEdit)
    {
    }
}
```

Sometimes programmers read strings from `submit` buttons I guess:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string button1, string button2 /*, ... */)
{
}
```

or both strings and models are received in a controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(string button1, Model model)
{
}
```

How controllers "know" that that ID is the ID one has to use etc. I would be grateful if someone could explain what exactly happens between View and controller. It's like the model is sent for us and it's up to us how we are going to receive it!

Another question would be on why some programmers read only IDs whereas the others read the whole objects etc.

Comment: Take a look at how the DefaultModelBinder works (http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx)

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta Thanks for the link. I read it and withing the text I have found [another link to a great post](http://www.codethinked.com/ASPNET-MVC-Think-Before-You-Bind) that explains most of what confuses me here :). Cheers!